# How to upload a video from a web application to YouTube using PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube

I need to upload the video from a web application to youtube and need to get the url of the video uploaded as response. Can any one tell how to do dis using php. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php youtube api :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged CodeIgniter, i assume thats a the framework you also want to use? If so theres a library that can help you see [the codeigniter wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/YouTube_API_for_CodeIgniter/)